# How to cross join unnest in PySpark?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, unnest

I have a table:

| Department | Name | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Finance | John Doe | 01/01/2022 | 01/05/2002 |
| Marketing | Mark Smith | 05/02/2022 | 08/03/2002 |

I want to transform the table with what a `cross join unnest` would do in SQL.

So the output I'm looking for is:

| Department | Name | Event | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Finance | John Doe | Start | 01/01/2022 |
| Finance | John Doe | End | 01/05/2002 |
| Marketing | Mark Smith | Start | 05/02/2022 |
| Marketing | Mark Smith | End | 08/03/2002 |

How can I achieve this with a PySpark dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the example you provided, [`stack`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#stack) can do it:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('Finance', 'John Doe', '01/01/2022', '01/05/2002'),
     ('Marketing', 'Mark Smith', '05/02/2022', '08/03/2002')],
    ['Department', 'Name', 'Start', 'End'])

df = df.select('Department', 'Name', F.expr("stack(2, 'Start', Start, 'End', End) as (Event, Date)"))

df.show()
# +----------+----------+-----+----------+
# |Department|      Name|Event|      Date|
# +----------+----------+-----+----------+
# |   Finance|  John Doe|Start|01/01/2022|
# |   Finance|  John Doe|  End|01/05/2002|
# | Marketing|Mark Smith|Start|05/02/2022|
# | Marketing|Mark Smith|  End|08/03/2002|
# +----------+----------+-----+----------+
```